# How can I recover an autohotkey script that has been over-written

Tags: data-recovery, autohotkey

I have an autohotkey script that is continuously running on my computer.  I inadvertently saved a blank script over it, but the original is still running in the background.

I tried to recover the original .ahk file using Recuva but that didn't work.

Typically with autohotkey I would right-click the green AHK "H" button in the taskbar tray, click "Edit This Script" and the problem would be solved.  Unfortunately, I have this script set for no tray icon so it does not appear in the tray.

Is there any way to toggle off "NoTrayIcon", or some command I can send that would open it for editing; perhaps something in the Sysinternals Suite that could do the trick, other third party software, etc.?

Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

Comment: I think you may be out of luck in this case. In the future, it may be advisable to bing a key to `Menu, Tray, Icon` to [re-show the icon](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_NoTrayIcon.htm). You can also [bind a key](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Edit.htm) to `Edit` to edit the current script when the tray icon is hidden.

Comment: Simply restoring the file from the recent backup is the right thing to do in such scenario. Do you have backups?

Comment: You could also try [using a hex editor](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/55863-recover-deleted-but-still-running-ahk-script/) to recover the script from the running process.

Answer (score 0):

Use a service such as OneDrive. Create a folder to hold all of your AHK scripts under the OneDrive folder. Onedrive creates up to 30 revisions for you. You can download older versions of any of your scripts this way.